# postfix: programmatically adding a user

Tags: email, postfix-mta, shell

I asked this question two months ago and got nary an answer. In fact I earned the tumbleweed badge for asking a question that garnered so little interest.

However, this seems like a straightforward question with a definitive answer and I really need to be able to do this.

If there's still no answers I'd sure appreciate if anyone has any ideas about any other forums that might help me out. I tried asking godaddy but I guess I don't spend enough money with them for this level of support.

Thanks and here's the question:

> I'm using a godaddy virtual dedicated
>   server, and the default email server
>   that comes bundled with it is postfix.
>   There is even a way to add domains and
>   user accounts through the godaddy
>   control panel.
>
> I am trying to figure out (1) exactly
>   what it is they are doing to create
>   new accounts via the control panel,
>   and then (2) how to do that via a
>   Linux shell script.
>
> I have never used postfix and have
>   been trying to wade through the man
>   pages and other documentation. It
>   appears that when the user accounts
>   are associated with a domain, then the
>   user accounts are "virtual". So far
>   I've discovered that when I use the
>   godaddy control panel to add a new
>   email account, it adds an entry into
>   /etc/postfix/turbopanel/virtual_alias.
>   Then, that entry also seems to get
>   committed to the binary
>   virtual_alias.db in the same
>   directory.
>
> I have manually replicated the process
>   of adding a new email address to the
>   virtual_alias file and then running
>   postmap
>   /etc/postfix/turbopanel/virtual_alias
>   to get the entry into the
>   virtual_alias.db file. This works, but
>   some steps are missing: I am not able
>   to send email to the added user, and
>   the user doesn't show up in the
>   godaddy control panel.
>
> I don't think a new Linux account
>   needs to be created for the virtual
>   alias. The accounts created via the
>   control panel DO NOT have an
>   associated entry in /etc/passwd.
>
> Any help is much appreciated.
>
> Jeremy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want to create virtual mailboxes or forwarders for these virtual users?

see doc on 
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox
/etc/postfix/vmailbox

Tim
//

Comment: I don't really know. However, I can tell you that my server does not have a vmailbox file in the etc postfix directory.